# Scala Copy() Odd Behavior

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, named-parameters

I'm experiencing an odd bit of behavior when I use the auto-generated copy() method that was added in Scala-2.8.

From what I've read, when you declare a given class as a case-class, a lot of things are auto-generated for you, one of which is the copy() method.  So you can do the following...

```
case class Number(value: Int)
val m = Number(6)

println(m)                     // prints 6

println( m.copy(value=7) )     // works fine, prints 7

println( m.copy(value=-7) )    // produces:  error: not found: value value

println( m.copy(value=(-7)) )  // works fine, prints -7
```

I apologize if this question has already been asked, but what is going on here?

Comment: was just going to ask this question for scala 2.11 as well. glad I saw the answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scala allows many method names that other languages don't, including `=-`.  Your argument is being parsed as `value =- 7` so it is looking for a method `=-` on `value` which doesn't exist.  Your workaround all change the way the expression is parsed to split up the `=` and the `-`.

```
scala> var foo = 10
foo: Int = 10

scala> foo=-7
<console>:7: error: value =- is not a member of Int
       foo=-7
       ^
```

Comment: Another workaround would simply be to put a spaces around your equals, so: `value = -7`